# Google Play beta testing and Campaign Referrer

Tags: android, google-play

I have my application installed on Google Play as a beta product and part of the application logic is to retrieve the referrer parameters that are sent by Google Play when an application is installed.  I have tested this using my own ADB broadcasts using the Android Studio and it works fine.

I am finding on beta that I am not receiving any broadcasts from google play and I assume that is because they do not broadcast for beta products when they are installed.

Can anyone confirm this for me or suggest a way that I test this properly in beta?

Comment: I could not even get an answer from Google amazingly enough when I assumed it would be a simple - yes the beta program does send broadcasts or no it does not! Support said it would have to be placed with a developer and no answer as yet.  I will update this if I find out, but as I could not wait I have implemented this by launching the app directly from the NFC tap and then calling my service rather than the app being launched by my service.  Still have the issue of knowing when the app is launched for the first time after install, but I think I remember seeing a post and will hunt it down.

Comment: hey @ZipNFC did you manage to find a way to test this?

Comment: Any response on this yet from Google?

Comment: Hi - sorry for the delay AndroidGecko & djunod coming in coming back.  No we could not find a way of doing this and can only assume the beta process does not send broadcasts like the live system.  To remove the risk we removed the need for this and achieved the same functionality with a more direct approach as described above which works better and happens to be more efficient for what we wanted to do.

Comment: damn im experiencing the same as you.... any response?

Comment: afraid they never came back and we moved on with the approach mention above - sorry @Qing

Answer (score 0):

The broadcast should work even if the install was made through the beta channel, but it's not 100% reliable due to system conditions.

In order to offer a most reliable channel to get information about installation and referrer, Google launched the [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) that helps you to track the referrer information directly from Google Play instead of listening for a broadcast.

You add this to your build file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
}
```

And, during the 1st execution, connect to the API and check the referrer information:

```
InstallReferrerClient mReferrerClient
...
mReferrerClient = newBuilder(this).build();
mReferrerClient.startConnection(new InstallReferrerStateListener() {...});
...
ReferrerDetails response = mReferrerClient.getInstallReferrer();
response.getInstallReferrer();
response.getReferrerClickTimestampSeconds();
response.getInstallBeginTimestampSeconds();
```

There is a [blog post with the announcement](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/11/google-play-referrer-api-track-and.html), for full details about implementation see the [Play Install Referrer Library](https://developer.android.com/google/play/installreferrer/library.html) and the [API reference documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/installreferrer/classes.html).

Comment: Hi,

Any idea how can I test it?